# Generic extension method can return type of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, types, extension-methods, ienumerable

I want to write an extention which have generic parameters. 
Let me show with code.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, int countOfEachPart) 
{
    //spliting value
}
```

This method is always returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`
But i want to return somethink like that `IEnumerable<TList<T>>`

For example;
if i passed `List<T>` i should return `IEnumerable<List<T>>`
if i passed `T[]` i should return `IEnumerable<T>[]`
etc.

---

I tried this code but i couldn't success

```
public static IEnumerable<TList<T>> Split<TList,T>(this TList<T> value, int countOfEachPart) where TList:IEnumerable<T> //or where TList:IEnumerable
{
    //spliting value
}
```

Is there any way to return passed IEnumerable type?

Comment: Return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`

Comment: @TimSchmelter firstly i coded like that but this is always returning IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> but i want to return passed parameter type.If i passed List should return List, but this code will return IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you most probably have to implement support for arrays and lists anyway, you have to write overloaded methods.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, int countOfEachPart)     

public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Split<T>(this IList<T> value, int countOfEachPart) 

public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split<T>(this T[] value, int countOfEachPart)
```

---

About the logic of the method (which is actually not part of the question, but had been discussed in your own answer): I've implemented a similar one, only based on IEnumerables. It looks like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Page<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageSize)
    {
        T[] sourceArray = source.ToArray();
        int pageCounter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (sourceArray.Length <= pageCounter * pageSize)
            {
                break;
            }
            yield return sourceArray
                .Skip(pageCounter * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);

            pageCounter++;
        }
    }
```

I'm not entirely happy with it, because of the `ToArray`. I would have preferred a solution where the whole thing is as lazy as possible and only iterates the source when iterating the result. It would be a bit more complicated and I didn't have the time. However, it can easily replaced by a better implementation later.

Comment: Yess @Stefan Steinegger its look like this is single way for my problem.
I'll use this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i finished my extension. 
I used both of @Stefan Steinegger and @Luaan answers. Thanks
This is final code of my extention.
I'm open your critics and suggestion

---

```
public static class Extension
    {
        private static IEnumerable<TList> Split<TList, T>(this TList value, int countOfEachPart) where TList : IEnumerable<T>
        {
            int cnt = value.Count() / countOfEachPart;
            List<IEnumerable<T>> result = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= cnt; i++)
            {
                IEnumerable<T> newPart = value.Skip(i * countOfEachPart).Take(countOfEachPart).ToArray();
                if (newPart.Any())
                    result.Add(newPart);
                else
                    break;
            }

            return result.Cast<TList>();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>> Split<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> value, int countOfEachPart)
        {
            IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> result = value.ToArray()
                                                                .Split(countOfEachPart)
                                                                .Select(p => p.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value));
            return result;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Split<T>(this IList<T> value, int countOfEachPart)
        {
            return value.Split<IList<T>, T>(countOfEachPart);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split<T>(this T[] value, int countOfEachPart)
        {
            return value.Split<T[], T>(countOfEachPart);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, int countOfEachPart)
        {
            return value.Split<IEnumerable<T>, T>(countOfEachPart);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `value.Count()` is vary bad. Consider that the IEnumerable you can potentially pass in may be an expensive linq expression. You should only iterate it once. The same problem with `for (...) { value.Skip()... }`. You could do some performance improvements for Lists and arrays. I have a similar method, I'll share it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`TList` is a type argument - it isn't generic. But it doesn't have to be:

```
public static IEnumerable<TList> Split<TList,T>
  (this TList value, int countOfEachPart) 
  where TList: IEnumerable<T>
```

Sadly, this doesn't allow type inference of `T`...

Comment: this is i a good solution. But this time i must call this method like that `list.Split<List<MyClass>,MyClass>(100);` So i don't like this. But even so thank you

Comment: @dermanyon Yes, hence the "sadly, this doesn't allow type inference of `T`" :)) It's a limitation of C# that hurts once in a while.

Comment: You right. You remarked this.  I couldn't understand first time what do you mean. Sorry for my English. Thank you.